# While sending an Outbound SMS in exact target, capture the message title

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

As we have multiple campaigns running, I would like to Update DE with last Message sent to subscriber. This i want to capture while sending an Outbound SMS in (MobileConnect) exact target. Or is there a way to capture it

Answer (score 0):

You can use ampscript in any outbound SMS. So you'll want to construct the message as a string, then use the UPSERTDE() method to write it to a DE along with the mobile number of the subscriber. And finally output the string into the message with %%=v(@message)=%%